# JSP expression multiple variables as output

Tags: jsp

I want to print the two values by using single jsp expression tag is it possible?

```
<% int a=5;
   int b=10;
   int c=a+b;    

%>
 The values of a,b and c are: <%=a,b,c%>
```

I have to individually write jsp expression for each variables or the above code is correct.. in jsp.

Thanks..

Comment: In future questions, post as well the results and errors which you're getting. Do not ask "Is it possible?". This testifies zero effort from your side. Just try and run it and post the error/exception message, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to String-concatenate them.

```
<%= a + "," + b + "," + c %>
```

Or display them individually.

```
<%= a %>,<%= b %>,<%= c %>
```

Note that what you're doing is an [oldschool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) way of using JSPs. Consider using EL.

```
${a},${b},${c}
```

---

**Update** as per the comments, you seem to now want print the comma at all, in contrary to what you initially presented in the question, here are the examples in the same order without printing the comma:

```
<%= a + "" + b + "" + c %>
```

```
<%= a %><%= b %><%= c %>
```

```
${a}${b}${c}
```

Comment: ok..thanks i will try i am new..and i just started learning it..but can you help me out with the old method only that if i have to print the values of a b and c i don't want "," comma in between then also i need to use concate + ??

Comment: If you don't want to print the comma, just remove it like so: `<%= a + "" + b + "" + c %>` or `<%= a %><%= b %><%= c %>` (or replace by a space). Makes sense, does it?

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.
you will have to write them individually in the following manner
......

```
<%=a%>
<%=b%>
<%=c%>
```